# Eclipse doesn't build my java files in web app project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have an open source project (WAR file) imported to my Eclipse.

I have all java code sources in `WEB-INF/src/...` folder.

I have `User` java file with following code:

```
public class User {
  public User () {}
  public void create (){}
  public void test(){}
}
```

Which `create` method has been made by the open source project creator, while `test` is new method that I create.

Then I tried to call from my `login.jsp`:

```
User user = new User ();
user.create();
user.test();
```

The `user.test();` returns error `The method test() is undefined for the type User`, while the rest works fine.

I tried to check the build class and it only has the `create` method. Tried to clean and build the project, still doesn't resolve my problem. What is the cause of this error? Eclipse seems doesn't build my project.

Comment: you have declare methods in constructor of class, that should show error by eclipse in first place

Comment: oops sorry. I put the method in wrong place here. Updated my post.

Comment: WEB-INF/src is a very odd place to put your source. It would normally be outside the webapp folder, with the compiled classes compiling into WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Check in your project properties > build path if WEB-INF/src is defined as source folder.

Comment: kiwiron: yes I thought so too, but now the issue resolved already. Gas: tried it but it gives error about package, so I re-tried my effort described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite strange since I did this before and didn't work, but now it works.

I resolve this problem by moving all the java codes from `WebContent/WEB-INF/src/<my-package>` to `Java Resources/src/<my-package>`